# How to compare two lists for Additions, Removals, and Changes without Linq? C#

Tags: c#

I'm having some trouble starting a project. I get *what* I need to do, but I'm stuck on *how* exactly to implement it. I'm by no means asking for someone to do this for me, just a push in the right direction. I was given a program when already made code. In this code there are two methods containing two lists of objects.

I'm supposed to take these two lists and compare them, looking for additions, removals, and changes that occurred between the two lists. I'm not allowed to use LINQ but it's supposed to be somewhat efficient. I guess I'm unsure on how to "pull" these lists from the methods and use them outside of there and then compare them. I know that I can use bits like `additions = newList.Except(oldList);` but I'm not sure how to implement that when the lists are made inside of these. Thank you for any advice!

Quick edit to the post here. I forgot to mention that there is a `Student` class that makes required values for the idNumber, firstName, lastName, studentYear, and studentRank. Which is what both lists hold and need to compare to each other.

I have tried something like so:

```
foreach (Student s in newList)
{
    if (!(oldList.Contains(s)))
    {
        additions.Add(s);
    }
}
```

and I know that there are bits like
`additions = newList.Except(oldList);`

but I am unsure how to work with these lists that are made in these separate methods. I am also unable to use LINQ, which is suggested in 99% of the posts I have seen for this kind of problem

Here is what the lists are created in:

```
public static List<Student> GetStudentsOld()
{
    var oldStudents = new List<Student>();

    oldStudents.Add(new Student("111", "Michael", "Tucker", "Junior", 10));
    oldStudents.Add(new Student("222", "Svetlana", "Omelchenko", "Senior", 2));
    oldStudents.Add(new Student("333", "Michiko", "Osada", "Senior", 7));
    oldStudents.Add(new Student("444", "Hugo", "Garcia", "Junior", 16));
    oldStudents.Add(new Student("555", "Cesar", "Garcia", "Freshman", 4));
    oldStudents.Add(new Student("666", "Fadi", "Fakhouri", "Senior", 72));
    oldStudents.Add(new Student("777", "Hanying", "Feng", "Senior", 11));
    oldStudents.Add(new Student("888", "Debra", "Garcia", "Junior", 41));
    oldStudents.Add(new Student("999", "Terry", "Adams", "Senior", 6));
    oldStudents.Add(new Student("211", "Bob", "Stephenson", "Junior", 150));

    return oldStudents;
}
```

```
public static List<Student> GetStudentsNew()
{
    List<Student> newStudents = new List<Student>();

    newStudents.Add(new Student("111", "Michael", "Tucker", "Junior", 10));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("222", "Svetlana", "Omelchenko", "Senior", 2));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("333", "Michiko", "Osada", "Senior", 7));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("311", "Sven", "Mortensen", "Freshman", 53));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("444", "Hugo", "Garcia", "Freshman", 16));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("555", "Cesar", "Garcia", "Freshman", 4));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("666", "Fadi", "Fakhouri", "Senior", 72));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("777", "Hanying", "Feng", "Senior", 11));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("888", "Debra", "Garcia", "Junior", 41));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("411", "Lance", "Tucker", "Junior", 60));
    newStudents.Add(new Student("999", "Terry", "Adams", "Senior", 6));

    return newStudents;
}
```

I am looking for a result such as

> Console.WriteLine("Here is the list of Additions: ")
>   Additions(GetStudentsOld(), GetStudentsNew(), additions);

and then display them.

Here is the list of Additions:

> "411", "Lance", "Tucker", "Junior", 60

Comment: You don't need to "pull" the lists from the methods. You simply need to create a variable to hold the lists  (so something that matches the return type of the method) and call the method when you initialize the variables. For example: `var newList = GetStudentsOld();`

Comment: Have you considered asking your instructor for help?

Comment: Linq and `IEnumerable` have their place, but don't fall into the trap of premature optimization.  In cases of multiple traversals, Linq can sometimes be slower.  However given the problem and sample size I don't think performance will be a problem.

Comment: I would ask my instructor, but he doesn't answer emails and this is due before our next meeting. So I'm just kind of winging it here.

Comment: Is the `Student` class unique on an identifier (maybe the first parameter of the class constructor)?

Comment: Focus on the 1% you found that don't use Linq. What did you find out?

Comment: Also are you supposed to track changes to existing students?  (Hugo Garcia demoted back to Freshman?)

Comment: @ParrishHusband Eventually, yes. But I'm just trying to find the lines that are different from the old list right now. I tried what Rufus suggested below and it just output the entire new list. I also tried what I showed above, which was ```foreach (Student s in newList)
{
    if (!(oldList.Contains(s)))
    {
        additions.Add(s);
    }
}``` This formatted poorly, sorry. I have it in the above post.

Answer (score 1):

Methods have a return type, and you can capture the value by setting a variable of the same type equal to the result of the method call:

```
List<Student> oldStudents = GetStudentsOld();
List<Student> newStudents = GetStudentsNew();
```

Then we can loop through these two lists just like any other collection, using a `for` or a `foreach` loop. We can search for new students in the old students collection by first looping through the new students list, and then for each new student, loop through the old students list and look for a match.

Note that this is a basic way to do this, but is not the most efficient way.

Also note that this assumes you've overridden the `Equals` method to do a comparison on two students. If you haven't and that's beyond what you've learned so far, then you can compare some unique Property (like `Id`) or set of properties (like `FirstName` `LastName`) to determine if there is a match.

For example:

```
List<Student> additions = new List<Student>();

// For each new student
foreach(Student newStudent in newStudents)
{
    bool foundMatch = false;

    // See if there is a match in the old students list
    foreach(Student oldStudent in oldStudents)
    {
        // If we find a match, set our variable and exit this inner foreach loop
        if (newStudent.Equals(oldStudent))
        {
            foundMatch = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Now that we're out of that inner loop, see if we found a match
    // If we didn't, capture this student in the additions list
    if (!foundMatch)
    {
        additions.Add(newStudent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not knowing what `Student` class looks like, I tense up a bit on `if (newStudent == oldStudent)`.  99% probably fine, but I've been burned before.

Comment: Hmm I tried something very similar to this and it seems to just output the entire new list. Does it compare each line in the old list to each line in the new list? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @ParrishHusband Good point, I updated the answer with a comment about that.

Comment: @BrendanBohlin Please update your question with the code you've tried so you can get some specific help.

Comment: @ParrishHusband the Student class defines an id number, first name, last name, student year, and student rank for the list. I'll add it to my overall post. Sorry about that!